# Is there a forum for general discussion?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a general discussion section? I'd like to post a few off-topic things as just a general chat with a whole community and wondered if there's a place to do so?

Comment: That's not the purpose of Stack Exchange. You could try a chatroom here or there if you want if you want more 'free' discussion here, but otherwise it's best to find a site more geared toward that sort of thing.

Comment: Ohhh thats cool haha thanks :)

Comment: @AdamDavis - that should come with a mental health warning, at least in regards to some of the rooms...

Comment: Forums all over the internets.  Why come here to ask?  Try Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the normal Q&A sites, there are chat rooms.  They are typically available in a link in the footer of each page, but a handy shortcut is to simply add `chat.` to the beginning of the site's URL:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com

http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com

And so forth.

Note that the chat rooms are created by other users, and while moderators will check on flagged posts in chatrooms and participate in some chatrooms, many are not considered actively moderated.